Cross Object Field on FlexiPage in 2GP Package Issue
Trying to version/validate a package and continually running into issues surrounding cross object fields on a flexipage.
Something went wrong. We couldn't retrieve or load the information on the field: Record.Object__r.Field__c
It's only these ones causing an issue. Any ideas why? The flexipage looks correct:

            
                Record.Object__r.Field__c
                RecordObject_rField_cField2
            
        
Is there an org setting I need to enable somewhere in the scratch def file?

I suggest you raise a support case. We have seen some scenarios where field paths get corrupted, and I wonder if this is related.

I can do that, thanks.

I've waited ages and nothing from Support.. I'm completely clueless. It only happens for cross object fields on dynamic forms. Anyone have any idea where to even look?

Is the Object you are refering through the relationship part of another package? for example is part of Field Service managed package? That could be the issue

My colleague and I ran into a similar problem when deploying cross-object fields on a FlexiPage in a managed package environment. After consulting with Salesforce Tech Support and conducting an internal investigation, we learned the following:
The issue occurs because, in a namespaced org, you must add the namespace prefix to related object names in the FlexiPage metadata. This behavior has been reviewed by the Product Team and is marked as "Working As Designed" (Internal Reference: W-16331777).
For example, using the namespace myns, we needed to update our XML like this:
<fieldInstance>
  <fieldItem>Record.myns__RelatedObject__r.SomeField__c</fieldItem>
  <identifier>RecordRelatedObject_rSomeField_cField</identifier>
</fieldInstance>

This update resolved our deployment issue. However, we understand that adding a namespace prefix makes the solution less generic. As a workaround, Salesforce suggests creating a formula field to store the data, which might work better depending on your use case.
If you are also facing this issue, ensure you add the appropriate namespace prefix or consider implementing the formula field workaround.
